# Get values of input from InnerHTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, innerhtml

I have a problem with getting values from inputs in c#. I have a scenario where some users see a different table. Each user has his own levelofapprove(from 1 to 5).

```
switch (levelofapprove_converted)
            { //HiringManager
                case 1:
                    id_hiringmanager_div.InnerHtml = @"<table class=""table"" id=""id_hiringmanager"" runat=""server"">
<td style=""height: 37px""><input type=""checkbox"" class=""form-check-input"" id=""id_check_claims"" runat=""server""></td></table>";
                    break;
                //IT
                case 2:
 id_hiringmanager_div.InnerHtml = @" <table class=""table"" id=""id_IT"" runat=""server"">                
                <tr>
                    <td style=""color: rgb(0,0,0); height: 37px;"">Delete User Access Rights</td>
                    <td style=""height: 37px""><input type=""checkbox"" class=""form-check-input"" id=""id_check_access_rights"" runat=""server""></td>
                </tr>
</table>";
                    break;
            }
```

Here is a design how it looks like, with InnerHtml I am populating div with a different table for each person.

```
<div runat="server" id="id_hiringmanager_div"></div>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
       <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onserverclick="btn_approve_Click" runat="server">Approve</button>
      </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

So when I am trying to get value from a checkbox or call for OnclickEvent nothing is happening. Error list says that is doesn't see such control.
Here is how i am trying to call them:

```
bool check_pending_leave = id_check_pending_leave.IsChecked;
```

Comment: You are missing quotation marks before the break; is this a typo?

Comment: also your checkbox does not have runat="server", you can't call it from codebehind this way without runat server flag.

Comment: I just deleted a lot from the source code for the question, code, its a typo

Comment: @SehaxX problem is that it doesn't see any inputs in this content

Comment: You mean, your id_hiringmanager_div is empty for all cases?

Comment: @SehaxX no, problem is that Error The name 'id_check_claims' does not exist in the current context
and this problem for every input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is that you are creating the inputs over a string. Also the runat="server" that I suggest will not help as the server doesn't know that they are created.

You have to options:
First is to create the html markup in the aspx/ascx files and put them in asp:panel and hide/show them with the codebehind logic you have.

Or you do it like you started and add on the inputs the tag name="id_check_claims" and then in code behind you need to call the inputs like:

```
//IMPORTANT: if checked it will return "on", not 1 or true
var strValue = Page.Request.Form["id_check_claims"];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a hidden field (server side variable) value to set checkbox value on click event of checkbox.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnClaim" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Value="0" />


<script type="text/javascript">
  function onclaim()
   {
     var idchkclaim = document.getElementById("id_check_claims");
     document.getElementById("hdnClaim").value = idchkclaim.checked == true ? "1" : "0";
   }
</script>
```

On sever side access to get the value of hidden field .